# is silverlight for developers or designers?

Tags: c#, silverlight

i am a junior c# programmer and would like to learn silverlight.
is silverlight for progrmmers or for designers?

Comment: Is CSS for programmers or designers?

Answer (score 4):

It is for neither - Silverlight is simply the branding for the runtime engine, library set, etc. The only thing that "uses" Silverlight directly is (broadly speaking) the browser.

The important thing for *developers* is Visual Studio ([regular](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/) or [Express:Web](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/)), and for *designers*: the [Expression](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/) suite. Both can contribute to a Silverlight project. Also consider that you may be targeting [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight), so even "Silverlight" becomes misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight is for both developers/programmers and designers.

The User Interface of a Silverlight application is defined in [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) script, which is based upon XML.

Microsoft explicitly target the [Microsoft Expression](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/) (specifically [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx)) suite of products at designers, whilst [Microsoft's Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx) is aimed at developers (although Visual Studio 2010 can be used for design work as well).

If you have a designer and a programmer working together to create the overall Silverlight application, you can utilise a programming [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) called [MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVVM) to help separate the concerns between the UI and the back-end functional program code.  This effectively allow the programmer to not really care about the names and ID values of specific UI elements that may have been defined by the designer, but simply to "[bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748857.aspx)" together specific User Interface elements with their "back-end" program code counterparts to create the complete Silverlight application.

Answer (score 1):

It is for both.

Answer (score 1):

Both,

As a programmer it's good to be familiar with the programming model, the related MVVM pattern, the object model etc.

As a designer you can build your designs in Blend and XAML. Then integrate them with the rest of the software

Answer (score 0):

Both.

Usually a developer will do it all, but using the [Expression products](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/), designers and developers can work on the same project to utilise their skills.

Answer (score 0):

I guess like most peep said, it is for both.
Being a developer myself, I tend to sway towards the coding.
But when I want to do animation, I will go back to xaml, which is way more simpler than doing in the code behind.
One good thing about silverlight that certainly prove that it is suitable for both is that, no matter how a designer place his UI and animations, and no matter how a developer codes, as long as 1 focus on functionality, another focus on UI.

Things will work out perfect, unless the designer deleted some UI that is suppose to have functionality. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's for both.
However you're also going to need both developer and designer to make it quite good.